# Rails 6 not auto-loading class properly in development (zeitwerk mode)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, ruby-on-rails-6, nameerror

My understanding is that Rails is able to auto-load classes properly named within the `app` folder, by default.

It's not happening for me, so I want to see if you can find an obvious issue with my code.

My folders/files:

```
app
   blueprints
      concerns
         ingredient_blueprint_concern.rb
      liqueur_blueprint.rb
   controllers
   models
   ...
```

```rb
#app/blueprints/concerns/ingredient_blueprint_concern.rb

module Concerns
  module IngredientBlueprintConcern
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      attributes :name
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/blueprints/liqueur_blueprint.rb

class LiqueurBlueprint < BaseBlueprint
  include ::Concerns::IngredientBlueprintConcern

  # ...
end
```

rails console:

```
> Concerns
=> NameError (uninitialized constant Concerns
   Did you mean?  Concurrent):
```

---

It seems related to the new Rails 6 **zeitwerk** mode. If I go back the the **classic** mode (with the code below), it seems to work fine:

```
# application.rb
config.autoloader = :classic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36054

Ok so turns out that the `concerns` folders are actually in the rails load paths, so it means they shouldnt be namespaced, the same way a class is `app/models` isn't in the `Models` namespace.

The fact that they were working in Rails 5 was some sort of side-effect that I wont get into here, but you can read about in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if we can get an answer on this ...

```
# app/foo/bar.rb

module Foo
  class Bar
    def output
      'worked'
    end
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):001:0> Foo
NameError (uninitialized constant Foo)

irb(main):002:0> Bar
Zeitwerk::NameError (expected file /Users/simon/Projects/tmp/test_module/app/foo/bar.rb to define constant Bar, but didn't)

irb(main):003:0> Foo
=> Foo
```

But

```
irb(main):007:0> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.include?("/Users/simon/Projects/tmp/test_module/app/foo")
=> true
```

And why does it work if I call `Bar` first and after `Foo`? Autoloading issue?

### Edit (Aug 1, 2020)

changing the file path to `app/foo/foo/bar.rb` made it work. For now a workaround for me.

Comment: First of all, since you're new, know that you can't post your own question as an answer to another.

Your "issue" isn't one, that's how rails always worked as far as I know. You don't need to namespace classes that are defined in files that are at the root of /app (or any of the folders in autoload_paths I guess.

When you define models, you dont define them in a Model namespace right? So it's exactly the same for your `foo` folder.

Comment: The reason I was confused, is that Rails 6 changed how concerns work a bit. Before, you dont have to namespace your concerns if there were in `models/concerns`. Now these concerns folders are in the autoload paths, so you dont.